# How can I make an activity communicate with a fragment in another activity to update its UI?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity with some EditTexts and 2 CheckBoxes (checkBoxElevator, checkBoxHeating) and a fragment that is in another activity. I want the CheckBoxes to communicate with some TextViews and EditTexts from the fragment (elevatorPercent, saveElevator, heatingPercent, heatingFees), so for example if the checkBoxElevator is clicked the elevatorPercent and saveElevator must be visible and vice versa.

I tried to deal with it with SharedViewModel and although my code doesn't have any errors when I run the app, the UI doesn't update. Sorry in advance if my code is messy or if my info is not precise, I'm a total beginner in Android Studio and in Kotlin.

**UPDATE:** I switched from SharedViewModel to Local Broadcast and used intent.putExtra() method to pass the information, but unfortunately the fragment UI still doesn't update. I also have a SQLite Database to store the information from the Second Activity. Any help would be appreciated.

SecondActivity.kt
package com.example.maintenancefeescalculator

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private lateinit var checkBoxElevator: CheckBox
    private lateinit var checkBoxHeating: CheckBox

    private fun saveAddressToDatabase(
        address: String,
        addressNumber: String,
        floors: String,
        flats: String,
        elevatorChecked: Boolean,
        heatingChecked: Boolean
    ) {
        val dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
        val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase

        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS, address)
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS_NUMBER, addressNumber)
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FLOORS, floors)
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FLATS, flats)
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ELEVATOR_CHECKED, elevatorChecked)
            put(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_HEATING_CHECKED, heatingChecked)
        }

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.AddressEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values)

        val intent = Intent("UPDATE_UI_ACTION")
        intent.putExtra("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", elevatorChecked)
        intent.putExtra("HEATING_CHECKED", heatingChecked)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        checkBoxElevator = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxElevator)
        checkBoxHeating = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHeating)

        val nextButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextButton)
        nextButton.setOnClickListener {
            val address = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.addressText).text.toString()
            val addressNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.addressNumText).text.toString()
            val floors = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.floorsNum).text.toString()
            val flats = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.flatsNum).text.toString()

            val elevatorChecked = checkBoxElevator.isChecked
            val heatingChecked = checkBoxHeating.isChecked

            saveAddressToDatabase(address, addressNumber, floors, flats, elevatorChecked, heatingChecked)

            val intent = Intent(this, ThirdActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

TenantsFragment.kt

```
package com.example.maintenancefeescalculator

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager

class TenantsFragment : Fragment() {

    interface OnButtonClickListener {
        fun onDoneButton(
            name: String,
            surname: String,
            floor: String,
            phone: String,
            email: String,
            sqMeters: String
        )
    }

    private fun updateUIForElevator(elevatorChecked: Boolean) {
        val elevatorPercent = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.elevatorPercent)
        val saveElevator = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.saveElevator)

        if (elevatorChecked) {
            elevatorPercent?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            saveElevator?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            elevatorPercent?.visibility = View.GONE
            saveElevator?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private fun updateUIForHeating(heatingChecked: Boolean) {
        val heatingPercent = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.heatingPercent)
        val heatingFees = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.heatingFees)

        if (heatingChecked) {
            heatingPercent?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            heatingFees?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            heatingPercent?.visibility = View.GONE
            heatingFees?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private var buttonClickListener: OnButtonClickListener? = null

    private lateinit var userName: EditText
    private lateinit var userSur: EditText
    private lateinit var userFloor: EditText
    private lateinit var userPhone: EditText
    private lateinit var userEmail: EditText
    private lateinit var userSqMeters: EditText
    

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    if (context is OnButtonClickListener) {
        buttonClickListener = context
    }
    val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

            Log.d("TenantsFragment", "Broadcast received!")

            val elevatorChecked = intent.getBooleanExtra("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", false)
            val heatingChecked = intent.getBooleanExtra("HEATING_CHECKED", false)

            Log.d("TenantsFragment", "Elevator Checked: $elevatorChecked, Heating Checked: $heatingChecked")

            updateUIForElevator(elevatorChecked)
            updateUIForHeating(heatingChecked)

            Log.d("TenantsFragment", "UI Updated for Elevator and Heating")
        }
    }

    val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction("UPDATE_UI_ACTION")
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).registerReceiver(receiver, filter)

    Log.d("TenantsFragment", "Broadcast receiver registered")
}

    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    Log.d("TenantsFragment", "onCreateView")
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tenants, container, false)


    userName = view.findViewById(R.id.saveName)
    userSur = view.findViewById(R.id.saveSurname)
    userFloor = view.findViewById(R.id.saveFloor)
    userPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.savePhone)
    userEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.saveEmail)
    userSqMeters = view.findViewById(R.id.saveSqMeters)

    val doneButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.doneButton)
    doneButton.setOnClickListener {
        val name = userName.text.toString()
        val surname = userSur.text.toString()
        val floor = userFloor.text.toString()
        val phone = userPhone.text.toString()
        val email = userEmail.text.toString()
        val sqMeters = userSqMeters.text.toString()

        var isValid = true

        if (phone.length != 10) {
            userPhone.error = "Please add a correct phone number."
            isValid = false
        }

        if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
            userEmail.error = "Enter a valid email address or keep it blank if the tenant doesn't have one"
            isValid = false
        }

        if (isValid) {
            buttonClickListener?.onDoneButton(name, surname, floor, phone, email, sqMeters)
        }
    }

    return view
}

    private fun isValidEmail(email: String): Boolean {
        return email.isEmpty() || email.contains("@")
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.kt

```
package com.example.maintenancefeescalculator

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.provider.BaseColumns

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_ENTRIES)
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ADDRESS_ENTRIES)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_USER_ENTRIES)
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ADDRESS_ENTRIES)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.db"

        private const val SQL_CREATE_USER_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE ${UsernameEntry.TABLE_NAME} (" +
                    "${BaseColumns._ID} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "${UsernameEntry.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME} TEXT)"

        private const val SQL_DELETE_USER_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${UsernameEntry.TABLE_NAME}"

        private const val SQL_CREATE_ADDRESS_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE ${AddressEntry.TABLE_NAME} (" +
                    "${BaseColumns._ID} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS} TEXT," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS_NUMBER} TEXT," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FLOORS} TEXT," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FLATS} TEXT," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ELEVATOR_CHECKED} INTEGER," +
                    "${AddressEntry.COLUMN_NAME_HEATING_CHECKED} INTEGER)"

        private const val SQL_DELETE_ADDRESS_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${AddressEntry.TABLE_NAME}"
    }

    object UsernameEntry : BaseColumns {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "username"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "username"
    }

    object AddressEntry : BaseColumns {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "address"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS = "address"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS_NUMBER = "address_number"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_FLOORS = "floors"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_FLATS = "flats"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_ELEVATOR_CHECKED = "elevator"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_HEATING_CHECKED = "heating"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `BroadcastReceiver` for this case. Moreover, `BroadcastReceiver` is generally used to get information broadcast by the Android system or vice-versa. For example, when a charger is plugged in, a broadcast is generated you can then receive this broadcast information in your app and do things according. As far as I know, what you did will probably broadcast your intent to other apps, so they can receive the information. Read more [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

You can achieve the required communication in the following 3 ways:

*Assumption : You want information from `SecondActivity` to pass to `TenantsFragment` which lies in `ThirdActivity`.*

1. Use Intent Extras and Bundles (For limited amount of data and non-complex data)

Pass the required data from `SecondActivity` to `ThirdActivity` using Intent Extras and the pass the data from `ThirdActivity` to `TenantsFragment` using Bundles. Read more [here.](https://medium.com/@haxzie/using-intents-and-extras-to-pass-data-between-activities-android-beginners-guide-565239407ba0)

Inside `SecondActivity.kt` pass the data with intent.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ThirdActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", elevatorChecked)
startActivity(intent)
```

Inside `ThirdActivity` get the data and pass to the Fragment.

```
// use appropriate null handling 

val elevatoChecked : String = intent.getStringExtra("ELEVATOR_CHECKED").toString()

// pass data to fragment using Bundle

val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", elevatoChecked)
val fragment = TenantsFragment()
fragment.setArguments(bundle)
```

Note : The above code for passing data to fragment is based on idea, that you are using `FragmentManager` to launch the fragment. If you are using the modern Navigation Components, you can adapt to the same.

Receive the data in the fragment

```
// inside your fragments onCreate get the data
val elevatoChecked: String = getArguments().getString("ELEVATOR_CHECKED")
```

2. Use SharedPreferences (For limited amount of data and non-complex data) Read more [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences?authuser=1)

In your `SecondActivity` save the data in SharedPrefs.

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putString("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", elevatorChecked)
    apply()
}
```

Directly read from SharedPrefs in your fragment.

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val highScore = sharedPref.getString("ELEVATOR_CHECKED", "defaultValue")
```

3. Use database.
   From complex data and huge amount of data, you should use a database, since you already saved the data in the database. You can easily get the data anywhere in you app. However, instead of using SQLite directly, I would highly recommend to use the modern way using Room Library, read more [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Notes :

1. Instead of using multiple activities, you should see if you can do the required work using a single activity and multiple fragments. As Single Activity Architecture is highly recommended, unless you have a large app with complex non-linked functionalities. This way you can easily use SharedViewModel to achieve easier communication.
2. Use NavigationComponents for navigation and for passing data from Activity to Fragments.
3. Use Room Library for database.

Comment: It worked! You are a life saver brother

Comment: Glad it worked. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a ViewModel across Activities. ViewModels are specifically meant for Single Activity Architecture, where you have multiple fragments and you can communicate within them.

You can pass data between activities using `Intext.putExtra()`.

Also, the data you are trying to pass seems like some preferences, so you should ideally use `SharedPreferences` to save it on device. It will also help to persist this settings across app sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will try to figure that out.

Comment: Can I have some help after the update? I've put Logs to check how the Broadcast is transferred and I moved the onReceive inside the onAttach. From the Logs I can see that the onReceive is never executed and it just skips to the end of onAttach where the "Broadcast receiver registered" message appears.

Comment: I have added a more detailed answer. Have a look, if it solves your issue.